# making R functions

Tags: r, function

I am trying to make function to change column types.

sample

```
df = data.table(commission = as.character(c("100 EUR", "200 EUR", "300 EUR")))
df$commission <- as.character(df$commission)

str(df)
 #Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
 #$ commission: chr  "100 EUR" "200 EUR" "300 EUR"
 #- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

function

```
colconv <- function(data,colname){
        data$colname <- gsub(data$colname, pattern = " EUR", replacement = "", fixed = T)
        data$colname <- as.numeric(data$colname)
        data
}
```

And I get...

```
colconv(df, commission)

#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
#$ commission: chr  "100 EUR" "200 EUR" "300 EUR"
#- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

it processes through R but it changes nothing.

Can anyone suggest how to make it work? or any other solution that is smarter?

Comment: You are literally writing a variable called `colname` with your function. You should not use `$` to try to interactively select a variable.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I thought by typing data at the end of the line would return the result of convert.

Comment: @thelatemail right, So is there a way to specify the certain column to iterate within the function ?

Comment: @silverrain `data[[colname]]`

Comment: You're probably better off just writing your function to act on a vector, and then call it to assign your new variable `colconv <- function(x){
  as.numeric(gsub(x, pattern = " EUR", replacement = "", fixed = T))
}` for instance. Then `df[, commission := colconv(commission)]`

Comment: @thelatemail Ah, this works like a charm. Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off just writing your function to act on a vector, and then call it to assign your new variable

```
colconv <- function(x){ as.numeric(gsub(x, pattern = " EUR", replacement = "", fixed = T)) }
```

...for instance. Then:

```
df[, commission := colconv(commission)]
```